# PWA on iOS after redirecting back from external oauth

Tags: ios, oauth, progressive-web-apps, http-redirect

I have a PWA. When a user goes through the oauth login flow they’ll be sent to an external site for authentication, afterwards they are redirected back to my site. On iOS this redirect doesn’t open up the PWA, but instead the default web browser out of the PWA.

Which strategies can I use to keep the user in the full screen PWA after the oauth?